# How To control touches on UIWebView? (iphone)

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I want to handle touches on UIWebView same as we can handle touches on UIView.I want to use methods like touches began,touch ended,etc in this app.I have to handle multiple events on different touching events on UIWebView.

In this app I am displaying image in UIWeb View and i have to make image size large and small on double touch and when the user taps on that image the next image should appear and again if the user double taps that image it should navigate to another page and if user swipes then also next image should appear.Thus,i have to handle four events on touching UIWebView.

Please anyone tell me how to do this.I have tried many codes but nothing has helped me.I also tried by making a uiview on uiwebview but only one event happens by this other events does not.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want to do it sounds as if you shouldn't be using a uiwebview at all. I suggest you reconsider your app's architecture: typically both touch events AND page navigation (both of which you're attempting) are handled in view controllers. Consider implementing a view controller that will handle these events.

Also, don't solicit code and ask for it hand-delivered via email. No one wants to write your code, and you won't learn anything that way anyway.

Comment: kevboh,we cannot increase or decrease the image size by tapping on it without using UIWebView,therefore i have used UIWebView.Thanks for your advice about sending code.I have Given email so that if someone have code then send to me and dont write new code.

Comment: You could easily scale the image using a uiimageview. cocoawithlove (http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/zoomingviewcontroller-to-animate-uiview.html) has a good example of zooming with just a uiview. it's far better to frontload your work and invest some time in figuring out uiviews so that you don't have to try and code around uiwebview's touch handling, which I guarantee will be much much much more work in the end.

Comment: Thanks dear,i think this post will surely help me.

Comment: hii kevboh,i have seen the code on http://cocoawithlove.com but in this we cannot zoom in and zoom out the image like we can do in a uiwebview. Can u please help me by giving some other code in which i can zoom in and zoom out the image as in uiwebview  .           Thanks .

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html